# String to JS object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a string similar to this:

`"{id:1,another:thing},{id:2,another:item}"`

How can I convert this in JS to an object array `[{...},{...}]`?

**EDIT**

- Many in the comments say the string is not valid JSON - I didn't claim it to be. I realise though there was a JSON tag to the question. My bad.
- I know I can format a string to resemble a JSON. I don't have the freedom to modify the string as such.
- For the above 2 reasons,  the question differs from the supposed duplicate.

Comment: It's not valid JSON, so you can't use `JSON.parse()` on it directly. You can either create a parser for your own syntax or use proper JSON when building the string in the first place.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee it won't work because there are *at least* two big problems: 1. this is a list of item not surrounded by `[]` 2. the keys and values are not surrounded by `"`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee that's correct - it's not valid JSON. For *at least* the reason I provided. So I don't know why you suggest `JSON.parse`

Comment: @Jbadminton I don't think this would work. `thing` and `item` will be a problem if they don't exist in scope.

Comment: Folks, OP here have a format different then JSON. It's totally ok. Please stop trying to coerce then into using JSON.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I agree, honestly. The only time JSON is mentioned is in a tag and...well, that tag gets misused a lot. It's sort of safe to ignore it. OP has a string that represents objects and wants to turn that into an actual array.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the tag so I removed it. Thank you @VLAZ

Comment: Well, I think the best option would be to separate each element with a regex, for example, loop them doing split by "," and by ":" to get each key-value pair and insert the valid objects in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this format, you are pretty close to converting to an object. It's not valid JSON but it's easy enough if we try to break down the problem:

1. Separate the objects so from `"{id:1,another:thing},{id:2,another:item}"` we can get an array where each item is an "object" and only contains what the key-values would be -> so each item is "{id:1,another:thing}"
2. Each "object string" is then actually split off into a string for the keys and values `{id:1,another:thing}` -> `"id:1"` and `"another:thing"`
3. The key-value *strings* can be split into key-value *pairs*: `"id:1"` -> `"id"` and `"1"`.

So, this will give you a blueprint with the building blocks for each object and their keys and values. Here is how this can work as just an

```js
let input = "{id:1,another:thing},{id:2,another:item}";

//capture objects like "{id:1,another:thing}"
const regexForObjects = /\{[^}]*\}/g;

let objectBlueprint = input
  .match(regexForObjects) //split off each "object" as a string
  .map(objString => objString.slice(1, -1)) //remove the first { and the last }
  .map(item => item.split(/\s*,\s*/)) // split each string representation of an object into strings for each key and value
  .map(item => item.map(subitem => subitem.split(/\s*:\s*/))) //split each key-value pair into a separate array.

console.log(objectBlueprint)
```

This is verbose - the implementation can be done in other ways but this gets the point across of what is happening by following the steps.

once this is done, all that's left is to build up objects from this. Each object is represented by an array that contains arrays of key-value pairs, so we can very simply implement a function take this and return an object:

```js
let input = [ ["id", "1"], ["another", "thing"] ];

let output = fromArrayToObject(input);

console.log(output)

function fromArrayToObject(keyValuePairs) {
  return keyValuePairs.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    
    return obj;
  }, {})
}
```

Right now, this only produces strings as values. It's hard to guess whether `"1"` is intended to be a string or a number. This works as a minimum implementation but you can also try to guess the type of the value:

```js
let number = guessType("1");
let boolean = guessType("true");
let nul = guessType("null");
let string1 = guessType("The quick brown fox");
let string2 = guessType("something");

console.log("should be number:", typeof number);
console.log("should be boolean:", typeof boolean);
console.log("should be null:", nul === null); //typeof null -> "object", so doing an equality check
console.log("should be string:", typeof string1);
console.log("should be string:", typeof string2);

function guessType(value) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(value)
  } catch (e) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

This is simplistic but can work for a lot of situations. If the string can be parsed into a primitive, then it's that primitive. If it cannot be, then it's just treated as a normal string.

Putting everything together, here is what this can look like:

```js
let input = "{id:1,another:thing},{id:2,another:item}";

//convert into the structure to build into objects
let objectBlueprint = input
  .match(/\{[^}]*\}/g)
  .map(objString => objString.slice(1, -1))
  .map(item => item.split(/\s*,\s*/))
  .map(item => item.map(subitem => subitem.split(/\s*:\s*/)));

//convert each object
let output = objectBlueprint.map(fromArrayToObject)

console.log(output);


function fromArrayToObject(keyValuePairs) {
  return keyValuePairs.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = guessType(value);

    return obj;
  }, {})
}

function guessType(value) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(value)
  } catch (e) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not valid json, so `JSON.parse` will not work.
It won't work because there are two big problems with your JSON:
 1. this is not an array because the items are not surrounded by `[]`
 2. The keys and values are not surrounded by `"`

Try to modify the JSON in a way that it looks like this:
`var jsonobject = '{"id":"1","another":"thing"},{"id":"2","another":"item"}';` 
Then you can add brackets to make it an array by doing this:
 `var json = '[' + jsonobject + ']';`
 After that you can use:
 `JSON.parse(json);`

Full code:

```
var jsonobject = '{"id":"1","another":"thing"},{"id":"2","another":"item"}';
var json = '[' + jsonobject + ']';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// obj now got an js object array.
```